# Text within piecewise defined functions

Tags: braces, inline

I want to place text within the definition of piece-wise defined function as:

[image: Text Inline Piecewise Function]

I tried this:

```
\begin{equation}
F_j(x, y) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if pixel (x, y) is a face pixel in I_j} \\
0, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

However, I keep getting "Missing $ inserted text" error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Underscores "`_`" are not allowed in text mode, so try `\text{if pixel $(x, y)$ is a face pixel in $I_j$}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler to type with the `cases*` environment from `mathtools`: the second alignment column is automatically in text mode. Needless to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  F_j(x, y) =
  \begin{cases*}
    1 & if pixel $(x, y)$ is a face pixel in $I_j$ \\
    0, & otherwise
  \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`\text` sets its contents in text mode. As such, any math content will need to be set using `$`...`$`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  F_j(x, y) = 
  \begin{cases}
    1  & \text{if pixel $(x, y)$ is a face pixel in $I_j$} \\
    0, & \text{otherwise }
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```